# Getting ALL Recurrsive Items from Sharepoint 2010 Calendar List using SPservices

Tags: spservices

Is there is any CAML quey  to fetch all the recurring events from SharePoint 2010 Calendar List. i.e not for single year or month.
Eusing the `<DateRangeOverlap>` CAML query we can get events of today, Month & year . but we need to get all the recurring events from the calendar list.

We tried the following CAML query to get recurrence events for a month:

```
var nextdate=yy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd+timeZone 

CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>" +
      "<FieldRef Name='ID' />"+
            "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='EndDate' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='Location' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='Dept' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='Description' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='fRecurrence' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='RecurrenceData' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='fAllDayEvent' />" +
        "</ViewFields>",

CAMLQuery: "<Query>" +
                    "<Where>" +
                    "<DateRangesOverlap>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='EndDate' />" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' />" +
                            "<Value Type='DateTime'>" +
                                "<Month/>" +
                            "</Value>" +
                "</DateRangesOverlap>" +
                "</Where>" +
                "<OrderBy>" +
                        "<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />" +
                "</OrderBy>" +
                "</Query>",

CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions>" + 
             "<CalendarDate>"+nextdate+"</CalendarDate>" +
            "<RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>v3</RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>" +
            "<ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>" +
        "</QueryOptions>",
```

If possible please share the code to get events between specific date(i.e from & to dates).

Answer (score 0):

```
"<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='fRecurrence'/><Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq></Where></Query>"
```

**EDIT:** You'll also need to include the recurrence field in ViewFields:

```
CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='fRecurrence' /></ViewFields>",
```